# Outlook marking php emails as junk

Tags: php, email, outlook

I need to send emails to local users. But problem Outlook thinks email is junk (phishing). Is it possible to add special header or something to solve this problem?

```
$to      = $email; 
$subject = 'Registration;
$message = '<html><body>';
$message = '<h3>Hello </h3> <br>Text Text<br>TextText: Text<br> Login name: '.$user_name ;
$message .= '</body></html>';
$headers = 'From: emailname@localdomain'. "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: MyName@localdomain' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' ."\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: May be unrelated to the question, but you are missing `'` to close the string for subject. Also, you are overwriting `$message` when using `=` twice in a row (missing `.=`)

Comment: @Sebi thank you but this illustrate my script structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following headers usually work for me:

```
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1';
$headers[] = 'From: E-Mail Name <emailname@localdomain>';
$headers[] = 'Reply-To: My Name <MyName@localdomain>';
$headers[] = 'Subject: ' . $subject;
$headers[] = 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Then when sending, just implode:

```
mail($to, $subject, $email, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

However, I would suggest using PHPMailer for your mail: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer